# Absolutely continuous and differentiation

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F$ is absolutely continuous on any closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$ and integrable on $\mathbb R$, and that its derivative $F'$ is also integrable on $\mathbb R$.

I couldn't show why $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} F(x)=0$. Any hints please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format your questions using MahtJax (see FAQ). It might also help to describe your thoughts and what you have tried yourself. Regards

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{x\to +\infty} F(x)$ does not exist, then we can find $\epsilon>0$ and an unbounded increasing sequence $x_k\to+\infty$ such that $|F(x_{k+1})-F(x_k)|\ge\epsilon$ for each $k$. Therefore, 
$$\int_{\mathbb R}|F'|\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}|F'|\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty\epsilon =\infty$$
a contradiction. Thus, $\lim_{x\to +\infty} F(x)$ exists. If it's a nonzero number, $F$ itself is not integrable on $\mathbb R$: see the answer by Abel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a Cauchy argument. Can you show that $|F(x) - F(y)| \to 0$ as $x,y \to \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

First note that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)-F(0) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x F^\prime(y)\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^\infty F^\prime(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Lets write $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = F(0)+\int_0^\infty F^\prime(y)\,\mathrm{d}y := c$ and suppose $c\neq 0$. Assume without loss of generality that $c>0$ (otherwise we regard $-F$).
By definition of the limit there is an $N\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x)>\frac{c}{2}$ for all $x>N$. Now $\displaystyle\int_N^\infty F(y)\,\mathrm{d}y > \int_0^\infty c\,\mathrm{d}y = \infty$. **Contradiction!**

Thus our assumption was false and $\displaystyle c=\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = 0$.

Comment: "suppose $c\ne 0$": you haven't shown that $c$ (the limit) exists.